# how to fix connection error when reload in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, connection, device, reload

[image]I'm working on Windows 7. first connection is working, but reload doesn't work and it says no device attached and check by "adb devices", turned to offline. Windows 10 works and no error.

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json under scripts you can add something like this :

`"android-dev": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && react-native run-android"`

Then you can simply run `npm run android-dev` and you're all set.

Comment: still show up on bottom bar that rno apps connected

Comment: open a new cmd and run only this and try `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, Also could please share a screenshot of the error

Comment: first connection worked but when i tried reverse right away it causes no attached device error :(

Comment: Is this same issue occurred when you reload the app using debug menu https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

Comment: where is your emulator?  actually, your emulator is not open.

Comment: are you running your app on an emulator or connected real device?

Comment: @Asad it's real device

Comment: what is the out put of the `adb devices`

Comment: @EL173 i tried npm install again and reconnect the device and run the way you said and it worked thanks!

Comment: @StephenLee then you can mark answer as correct 

Comment: @EL173 already did! but could you explain how? how the "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081" work on server?